# Ruby string concatenation with integers (codepoints?)

Tags: ruby, string, integer, concatenation

So, I'm bored, and I've found what appears to be a strange inconsistency I was hoping to find more information on.  This deals with string concatenation in Ruby, particularly appending what the string documentation refers to as a "codepoint".

Here're some examples:

```
'' << 233 #=> "é"
'' << 256 #=> "Ā"
```

Now, the curious thing is that in IRB both of those examples work.  However, if you create a ruby class in a file, load the file, and execute the code, it blows up.  See following example:

```
class MyConcatenationTest
  def self.test
    '' << 233
    '' << 256
  end
end
```

And then in IRB:

```
load 'my_concatenation_test.rb'  #=> true
MyConcatenationTest.test         #=> RangeError: 256 out of char range
```

So, my question is this:  Why does this work in IRB, but not when I load a script that runs the same line of code?

Some other things to notice, if you alter the class:

```
class MyConcatenationTest
  def self.test
    '' << 233
    #'' << 256
  end
end
```

... and then reload/run the method, it returns the \x escaped value for 233 instead of the "é" from before:

```
load 'my_concatenation_test.rb'
MyConcatenationTest.test          #=> "\xE9"
```

So... what's up with that?  Both strings have the same encoding (UTF-8), and changing it to ASCII doesn't seem to make any difference.

EDIT:  I should mention that I used 256 in the example above because that's the lowest number it blows up on.  It's pretty obvious that it's freaking out because it can't properly deal with anything higher than "\xFF".  To clarify my question, I'm curious to know why this limitation exists when the code exists in a loaded ruby file, but not in IRB.

Comment: No it is good for me.. I didn't get any error. In which Ruby version you are?

Comment: @ArupRakshit It fails in Ruby 1.9.3-p429, but works in 2.0.0 for me.

Comment: Then, the question is why it works in irb.

Comment: Maybe IRB runs a different Ruby version than your system. Add `puts RUBY_VERSION` to check that.

Comment: @mbratch Yes I tested on Ruby2.0.0-p0, but forgot to mention that.. sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks @ArupRakshit. Ruby 1.9.3-p429 works for me if I include the "magic" comment, `# ~coding: utf-8`.

Comment: I'm running ruby 1.9.3p194.  When I run "puts RUBY_VERSION" in IRB, it says "1.9.3".  I'm not sure why IRB uses UTF-8, but loading a codefile would not. It is, however, clear that it does run differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which ruby version do you use? It's is probably because in ruby 1.9 (and earlier) UTF-8 is not the default encoding.

Modifying your file to the following advises ruby to use UTF-8 to parse your file.

```
# ~coding: utf-8
class MyConcatenationTest
  def self.test
    '' << 233
    '' << 256
  end
end
```

If you execute the file in ruby 2.0, it works as expected without [the magic comment](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Encoding.html#label-Script+encoding), because UTF-8 is the default encoding in ruby 2.0.

### Why does it work in irb (even with ruby 1.9.3)?

`irb` uses the `$LANG` environment variable to determine which encoding it should use. My (and maybe your?) `$LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, which makes `irb` use UTF-8 encoding.

You may start your `irb` with `irb -EISO-8859-1` (or some other encoding) to change that.

```
$ irb -EISO-8859-1 # start irb with ISO-8859-1 encoding
irb(main):001:0> "".encoding
=> #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
```

Comment: It fails on Ruby 1.9.3-p429

Comment: @mbratch with or without the magic comment? It works for me with the comment in 1.9.3-p392 (oh, I should update my dusty 1.9.3 :)

Comment: I have seen `#encoding 'utf-8'` but not the magic one `# ~coding: utf-8`. Documentation please for myself..:P

Comment: @tessi haha. 1.9.3-p429 fails for me with or without the `#encoding 'utf-8'` comment. But it works with the `# ~coding: utf-8` comment. 2.0.0 works regardless.

Comment: How very interesting.  I didn't think about the encoding used for the code-file at all, and only checked that the string encoding was UTF-8.  Thanks much for the fast answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit you find the mri implementation of the magic comment here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/7ea675732ac1dac72f07756498706678d8725719/lib/rdoc/encoding.rb#L77

Comment: I wanna +1 this answer, but I don't have 15 reputation yet.  Once I do, I'll come back and give it its proper credit.  Thanks for the very thorough explanation.